# sunOS's sed in bash script - replace pattern: nothing changes

Tags: bash, sed, sunos

ANSWER:

as [mlv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132261/mlv) and [sorontar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6843677/sorontar) mentioned, my SED version is BRE and doesn't support | (pipe). so in my case is possible use something like:

```
sed "s/\( [namevlu]*=\"\)BASE\.$str1/\1BASE\.$str2/g"
```

which match *name="* and *value="* **but not** *other="* and *values="*. regex ( [namevlu]) contains only characters what i need. ok, it is not as save, as can be, but i don't expect existence of something like *valuenm="* or so. if someone needs **exactly** specified regex, it needs make two (or more) seds.

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I need to replace one string with another, but for sure i need check specific context.

for example:

*blah val1="BASE.OLD_TEXT_OR_SO" blabla

blah val2="BASE.OLD_SOMETHING" ...*

i want change to

*blah val1="BASE.NEW_TEXT_OR_SO" blabla

blah val2="BASE.NEW_SOMETHING" ...*

this script doesn't change anything:

```
#!/bin/bash

...

str1="OLD_"
str2="NEW_"

sed "s/\(name=\"|value=\"\)BASE\.$str1/\1BASE\.$str2/g" input.file > output.file
```

but later similiar sed works ok:

```
sed "s/\(<Tag>\)[A-Z0-9\-\._|]*\(<\/Tag>\)/\1$otherStr\2/g" input.file > output.file
```

output file has still *BASE.OLD_* :/

also when i try it on console, i get same (none) result. i think there is something wrong in "looking for" pattern, but i havent idea what.

```
$ str0='blah name="BASE.OLD_TEXT_OR_SO" blabla 
> blah value="BASE.OLD_SOMETHING" ...
> blah other="BASE.OLD_SOMETHING" ...
> blah values="BASE.OLD_SOMETHING" ...'
$ echo $str0  | sed "s/\(val1=\"|val2=\"\)BASE\.$str1/\1BASE\.$str2/g"
```

regex was tested on [online tester](https://regex101.com) where it works fine.

```
(name="|value=")BASE\.OLD_
\1BASE\.NEW_
```

system:
SunOS 5.11
GNU bash 4.1.11(1)-release
Sed 4.2.1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: str0 has a new line? As in your question? Can you update the variable properly?

Comment: str0 has newline, it is just for test in console (echo str0 | ... ) .. originally data are taken from input file.

Comment: Why can't you replace the pattern directly in the file? just provide the part in the file you want to replace with

Comment: in script im using sed "s/\(val1=\"|val2=\"\)BASE\.$str1/\1BASE\.$str2/g" input.file > output.file where isnt $str0. $str0 is just for test it in console with echo $str0  | sed "s/\(val1=\"|val2=\"\)BASE\.$str1/\1BASE\.$str2/g" ... main problem is in script. str0 is not important. i edit it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as [mlv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3132261/mlv) and [sorontar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6843677/sorontar) mentioned, my SED version is BRE and doesn't support | (pipe). so in my case is possible use something like:

```
sed "s/\( [namevlu]*=\"\)BASE\.$str1/\1BASE\.$str2/g"
```

which match *name="* and *value="* **but not** *other="* and *values="*. regex ( [namevlu]) contains only characters what i need. ok, it is not as save, as can be, but i don't expect existence of something like *valuenm="* or so. if someone needs **exactly** specified regex, it needs make two (or more) seds.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure SunOS sed includes |. That would be added with -r which I don't think SunOS sed supports.

But in this case, you should be able to do:

```
sed "s/\(val[12]=\"\)BASE.$str1/\1BASE.$str2/"
```

If you can't use val[12], then I don't think it can be done in sed. But it's not too hard in perl:

```
perl -pe "if (/val1=BASE.$str1/ || /val2=BASE.$str1/) {s/BASE.$str1/BASE.$str2/;}"
```

Comment: i think yes, but, right now i cant test it. about val[12]: in real script im using name=" and Object=" words. so if youre right and sunOS doesnt have | (pipe), it will be next challenge for me :D

Comment: I was afraid of that.

Answer (score 1):

In [a basic sed only BRE are supported](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02), [(POSIX BRE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) and the alternation (`|`) does not exist.
Your regex must be written as:

```
sed "s/\(val[12]=\"BASE\.\)${str1}/\1${str2}/g" input.file
```

If, the version of sed you use supports [(extended) ERE (which accepts the `|`)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04) then you may use:

```
sed -E "s/(val(1|2)=\"BASE\.)${str1}/\1${str2}/g" input.file
```